# how to access a simple node.js server from another network (not local network)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, localhost

I have made a very simple node.js server. I am able to access it in my local network but I want someone Otherside of the network to access it(Globally).

```
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')
const server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('index.html', function(error, data) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type' : 'text/html'})
        res.write(data)
    })
})
server.listen(3000 , function (error) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("error :", error);
  } else console.log("Server listening on port:", port);
});
```

Comment: You need to setup [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) on your router.

Comment: is there a complete video or blog which contains the tutorial?

Comment: it is different for every router and internet service provider, you are most likely going to have to refer to your routers manual

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like **Ngrok** to expose your project/server outside. It is a npm package (visit the npm package  page [LINK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrok)).

Follow this guide [LINK](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/exposing-your-local-node-js-app-to-the-world)

```
npm install ngrok -g
ngrok http 8080
```

Comment: Thanks but I wanted to do it all by myself rather than using a module.